# CriteriaBuilder JPA: Multiselect in Subquery / groupby / maxresult

Tags: jpa, persistence, criteria-api

Currently I'm working on a "filter"-function for a customer list.

I have this following subquery and I'm not sure if there is a way to build this with the CriteriaBuilder. It would also work without the multiselect `b.date, ...` but I need `Group By`, `Order By` and `Limit` in order to select the min value. The result should be a single number.

```
SELECT (COALESCE(SUM(b.account1),0) + COALESCE(SUM(b.account2),0) + COALESCE(SUM(b.deposits),0)) AS SUM FROM customer_balance b WHERE b.client_nr = '123455'
GROUP BY b.date
ORDER BY SUM
LIMIT 1
```

e.g. Customer Balance Table

```
"client_nr","date","account1","account2","deposits"
"1234567","2018-02-28",204600.0,82500.0,21120.0
```

UPDATE:
This is my code currently, but

```
Subquery<BigDecimal> CustomerBalanceSubQuery = CustomerQuery.subquery(BigDecimal.class);
Root<CustomerBalance> CustomerBalance = CustomerBalanceSubQuery.from(CustomerBalance.class);

Expression<BigDecimal> currentAccount = criteriaBuilder.sum(CustomerBalance.get("currentAccount"));
Expression<BigDecimal> overnightDeposits = criteriaBuilder.sum(CustomerBalance.get("overnightDeposits"));
Expression<BigDecimal> termDeposits = criteriaBuilder.sum(CustomerBalance.get("termDeposits"));

CustomerBalanceSubQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.sum(termDeposits, criteriaBuilder.sum(overnightDeposits, currentAccount)));
Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(CustomerBalance.get("id").get("ClientNr"), Customer.get("ClientNr"));
CustomerBalanceSubQuery.where(predicate);

// adding to main-query
queryPredicateList.add(criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.greaterThan(CustomerBalanceSubQuery, BigDecimal.valueOf(liquidity))));
```

- How can I add `orderBy` for my subquery?
- How can I set `maxResult`?

Thanks!
B

Comment: Why do you want to use Criteria API when you already have a working query?

Comment: All JPQL queries should be buildable using Criteria. First you should post WHAT you have tried, and what part you have a problem with. Clearly that above is not JPQL, so post the JPQL

Comment: @SimonMartinelli my query is dynamic. Depending on the query params I have to query different tables and thats actually my challenge. I need a subquery to get the min value of three sum grouped by date in a different table.

Comment: @BillyFrost you are right, I updated the question.

Comment: Why do you think you need a subquery? I'd try with a simple query using an `Expression<BigDecimal> mySum = criteriaBuilder.<BigDecimal>sum(...)` holding the result of the sum. Then I'd apply the sorting on this expression `cq.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.desc(mySum))` and finally on the resulting query apply the `setMaxResults()` method

Answer (score 0):

After talking to some colleagues I refactored the query to:

`SELECT min(COALESCE(b.current_account,0) + COALESCE(b.overnight_deposits,0) + COALESCE(b.term_deposits,0)) FROM customer_balance b WHERE b.client_nr = '123456'`

And the code...

```
Subquery<BigDecimal> customerBalanceSubQuery = customerQuery.subquery(BigDecimal.class);
Root<CustomerBalance> customerBalance = customerBalanceSubQuery.from(CustomerBalance.class);

Expression<BigDecimal> currentAccount = customerBalance.get("currentAccount");
Expression<BigDecimal> overnightDeposits = customerBalance.get("overnightDeposits");
Expression<BigDecimal> termDeposits = customerBalance.get("termDeposits");

customerBalanceSubQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.min(criteriaBuilder.sum(termDeposits, criteriaBuilder.sum(overnightDeposits, currentAccount))));
Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(customerBalance.get("id").get("clientNr"), customer.get("clientNr"));
customerBalanceSubQuery.where(predicate);

queryPredicateList.add(criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.greaterThan(CustomerBalanceSubQuery, BigDecimal.valueOf(liquidity))));
```

Anyway, it would be interesting to see the query from the original question.
Other than @BillyFrost mentioned, I'm not sure if every sql query is buildable with the Criteria API.